# Eclipse CDT: Complete function definition parameters

Tags: eclipse

[NB: I did find essentially [the same question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766003), but it has no answers, and I thought this site might be a better match.]

When using Eclipse Mars CDT, if there's a visible function declaration, possibly in a different included file, like

```
class Thing {
public:
    void myfunc(unsigned int count,
                bool something_special,
                const Other* other_obj) const;
};
```

and I then start to type a function definition, like

```
void Thing::myfunc(
```

then Eclipse will show a popup hint window containing the parameter types and names from the matching declaration (or a list of declarations for an overloaded function), whenever:

- I pause after typing the `(` character, or
- I do the Content Assist action with the cursor anywhere inside the `()`, or
- I do the Parameter Hints action with the cursor anywhere inside the `()`.

This is useful as a reminder of what the declaration had, and I can visually copy from it as I type.  But often I'll just want to use exactly the types and parameter names as they appear in the declaration, or possibly start with those and then edit them a bit.  Is there any easy way to get Eclipse to just populate the entire function parameter list (after I choose an overload when appropriate)?